# Change paragraph breaks to line breaks

Tags: vba, outlook

Before sending an email, I want to change paragraph breaks to line breaks. Instead of using Replace, I'd like to run a macro. The following, placed in ThisOutlookSession, will not save as a macro. I assume because you cannot pass arguments??? But where do I place the code?

```
Private Sub ChgParagraphsToLineBreaks(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Item.Body = Replace(Item.Body, "^p", "^l")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sub  has to be called in the [Application.ItemSend()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx) event which is triggered  when an email is being send. You can also cancel the sending in this event.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    ChgParagraphsToLineBreaks Item

End Sub

Private Sub ChgParagraphsToLineBreaks(ByVal Item As Object)
    dim strBody as string
    strBody = Item.Body
    strBody = Replace(strBody, "^p", "^l")
    Item.Body = strBody
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Follow up. Is there a VBA code to select the entire body (like CTRL+A)? The above replace does not work unless the body is selected (at least that's what is happening to me).